# Django: Bootstrap button link doesn't work

Tags: django, django-views, bootstrap-modal

I created a link in my polls application of Django and it looks like my Button links doesn't work. What is the mistake I am doing here?

My urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    #url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),


    url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),

    # ex: /polls/5/
    # the 'name' value as called by the {$ url $} template tag
    #url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    #url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),

    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<ballot_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),

]
```

And I create buttons and links like this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="{% url 'polls:index'  %}"></a>
  {% bootstrap_icon "home" %}
</button>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="{% url 'polls:login'  %}"></a>
  {% bootstrap_icon "user" %} User Login
</button>
```

In inspector it looks like [image]

Comment: If you right-click on one of this buttons and inspect it, what is the value of the `href` attribute?

Comment: When I right click and inspect I see that <a href="/polls/"></a>. Updated my question with a screenshot of inspector.

Comment: OK. That looks nice. And if you press on the `index` one, what do you get?

Comment: Both of them doesn't work.

Comment: So, when you click it you get nothing. What about if you hardcopy `/polls/` in the address bar? Do you get a 404 or something?

Comment: Hard copy does work for both the links. Like 127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ and 127.0.0.1:8000/polls/login. But unable to traverse using buttons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139991/discussion-between-sandeep-thota-and-nik-m).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 solutions to this:

Either place the `<a>` outside of the `<button>`, like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:index'  %}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">{% bootstrap_icon "home" %}</button>
</a>
```

or leave only the `<a>` (and remove the `<button>`), like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:index'  %}" class="btn btn-primary">{% bootstrap_icon "home" %}</a>
```

Comment: First one works. Second one is not showing button instead it is showing class name details icon as text.

Comment: It depends on what the `{% bootstrap_icon "home" %}` renders. If the 1st one works for you, go for it!